# Excel VBA to search for specific text in cell and then copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, copy, paste, vba

I want to make a macro to copy `Date` from cell `J5`, copy `Invoice No.` from cell `H6`, copy `consumer name` from merged cells `A6` and copy only the amount of the items under product description cell range (B11:B21) for items in invoice sheet and paste those values into another sheet by name invoice-record there is table with headers `consumer name, date, Invoice No. Items`

(Sub Headers of Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item6, Item7, Item8, Item9, Item10, Item11, Item12)

I want my macro to copy these values from Invoice sheet and paste under the headers of each in the table in Invoice-Record sheet. to elaborate it better, I am giving the link of the workbook:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wu69cgn3qfvr67/Invoice.xlsx?dl=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by moving the data you KNOW moves by setting the values in the beginning.
The tricky part is checking for each item.

Since you know there are 12 of them, as long as the example you provided is how it's going to be laid out, you just loop through a count of 12 and for each one, compare the items in the Invoice to the Product Number, if it's on the invoice, it will be set in the appropriate column on the target sheet.

**TESTED:**  using your example sheet, see screenshots.

```
Sub InvoiceRecord()

Dim source As String
Dim target As String
Dim tempCode As String
Dim tempItem As String
Dim prodCode As String
Dim count As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim tRow As Long
Dim lastTRow As Long

    source = "Invoice"
    target = "Invoice-Record"

    lastTRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    tRow = lastTRow + 1    'New row on target Sheet

    'Move the General Invoice Info over to Target
    Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, "A") = Sheets(source).Range("A6").Value  'Consumer
    Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, "B") = Sheets(source).Range("J5").Value  'Date
    Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, "C") = Sheets(source).Range("H6").Value  'Invoice No
    Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, "P") = Sheets(source).Range("J23").Value 'Net Amount

    'Now establish which Items have to move over

    For count = 1 To 12         'Looking for each of the 12 Items

        prodCode = "i" & count  'Set a Product Code based on "i"n  n = count
        lCol = count + 3        'The column number is 3 more than ProductCode Number

        For lRow = 11 To 22     'Loop through each row on the Source
            If Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "A").Value > 0 Then
                tempCode = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "C").Value    'Get temp product code for row

                If tempCode = prodCode Then    'Insert the Qty in the Column for that item
                    Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, lCol) = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "A")
                End If
            End If
        Next lRow
    Next count
End Sub
```

[image: Invoice]
[image: RECORD]